# 2D Array as OpenCL kernel argument

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, opencl

Pretty straight forward question: How would one use a 2D array as an OpenCL kernel argument?

Common sense suggests using

`__kernel void main(__global <datatype> **<name>)`,

however the compiler doesn't seem to be quite amused by this idea:

`kernel parameter cannot be declared as a pointer to a pointer`.

Am I overseeing the obvious, or what exactly is it, I am doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

The hosts (c++) datastructure looks like this:

`vector<vector<Element>>`,

where Element is a struct containing the indexes of the child nodes inside the very same array. Basicly pointers.

Comment: you can't pass a pointer as a global variable in opencl. will an image/texture work for your purpose? or a 1D array?

Comment: I am passing an array of trees stored as arrays of structs themselves, so an image would not suit my purpose at all. I can think of using a 1D array, but I'm not fairly certain whether this would work or not.

Comment: are the trees balanced? could they be structured into a 1D array each? you are allowed to call the kernel many times with different params if you have to

Comment: Implied in most answers but never stated directly: `vector<vector<Element>>` does not have elements contiguous in memory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to reduce the 2D array down into a 1D array.

Host:

```
int array[50][50];
int * ptr_to_array_data = array[0];
int width = 50, height = 50;
cl_mem device_array = clCreateBuffer(/*context*/, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, 50 * 50 * sizeof(int), ptr_to_array_data, /*&err*/);
clSetKernelArg(/*kernel*/, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &device_array);
clSetKernelArg(/*kernel*/, 1, sizeof(cl_int), &width);
clSetKernelArg(/*kernel*/, 2, sizeof(cl_int), &height);
```

Device:

```
kernel function(global int * array, int width, int height) {
    int id = get_global_id(0);
    int our_value = array[id];
    int x = id % width; //This will depend on how the memory is laid out in the 2d array. 
    int y = id / width; //If it's not row-major, then you'll need to flip these two statements.
    /*...*/
}
```

If your 2D array is not stored contiguously in memory like my example implies, you'll need to roll your own function to make sure that the entire memory is stored contiguously in a single heap-allocated object.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I also would not recommend using an image for this kind of data processing, as access to an image usually requires a sampler, which involves abstracting your accesses in a way that will encourage errors and difficult-to-read code.

Comment: Or, viewed another way, accessing images using samples and dedicated functions prevents you from having to do ugly math to find elements, supports many different pixel types with a single kernel, allows bounding, mirror or repeat, and offers access to the hardware bilinear interpolation if you want it.

Comment: @Dithermaster All of which are extremely useful if the data you're working with is actual image data. But if you're working with data structures or non-image data (as the OP appears to be), it just adds layers of complexity for little perceivable benefit.